# Tracking Google Analytics on a 1 page website using hashtags

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, analytics, tracking

I have a long single page website using hashtags in the URL when you get to a certain section from scrolling or clicking. What technique can I use to track these hashtags as "pages" in google analytics?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to track hash links like pages with google analytics?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811172/is-it-possible-to-track-hash-links-like-pages-with-google-analytics)

Comment: I was looking for something more like this.
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sup>(Recycling from a [prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811172/is-it-possible-to-track-hash-links-like-pages-with-google-analytics)...)</sup>

Generically, your code could look like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview',location.pathname + location.search  + location.hash]);
```

You could either bind that code to every time you have a hash change within your application, or you could use a [generic hashchange plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/), that uses the HTML5 onhashchange, and some backwards compatible hacks for older browsers, and bind this code to that event, so that it fires every time your hash changes.

Using that plugin, your code could look like:

```
$(window).hashchange( function(){
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview',location.pathname + location.search  + location.hash]);

})
```

Comment: add: try { _gaq.pus(..... } catch (e) {} - because some user block GA eq adblock or Ghoster extension

Comment: If they do that, then _gaq will just be a vanilla JavaScript array, and it won't throw any errors.

Comment: ReferenceError: _gaq is not defined.

Comment: That just indicates you haven't instantiated GA in the recommended way. The above code should not replace the standard GA snippet.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, virtual pageviews is your solution, here's the tutorial: http://services.google.com/analytics/breeze/en/et_vps/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use google analytics something like this

```
 onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/PDF/EXAMPLE PDF NAME']);"
```

in your google analytics it will then record a click in the folder structure you specify

Comment: urchinTracker is deprecated and should not be used. Updated to include current syntax.