# Google Analytics - Using parent.location.hash in JS has no effects

Tags: javascript, hash, google-analytics

In our website we're using steps to complete a form, every step has its own "continue" button to proceed to next step ,and so on until user finish all steps. The thing is we are using `parent.location.hash` to handle hash in our url for current step and at the same time we need to track in GA. So basically here is our code:

```
switch (hash) {
  case 'step_0':
  parent.location.hash = 'warning';
  ga('send', 'pageview', '/#warning');
  break;
  case 'step_1':
  parent.location.hash = 'categories';
  ga('send', 'pageview', '/#categories');
  break;
  case 'step_2':
  parent.location.hash = 'names';
  ga('send', 'pageview', '/#names');
  break;
  case 'step_3':
  parent.location.hash = 'city';
  ga('send', 'pageview', '/#city');
  break;
  case 'step_4':
  parent.location.hash = 'members';
  ga('send', 'pageview', '/#members');
  break;
  case 'step_5':
  parent.location.hash = 'privacy';
  ga('send', 'pageview', '/#privacy');
  break;
}
```

easy, but the thing is no track is being recorded, so what am I missing?? any ideas? thanks.

**update: the url with the hash looks similar as this: `https://example.com/#warning`**

Comment: By default Google does not track things after the fragment identifier, so all those Urls would be recorded simply as "/". You could use query strings in your virtual url paths ("?step=names" etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Try the solution from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811172/is-it-possible-to-track-hash-links-like-pages-with-google-analytics#answer-4813223) and do:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'page': parent.location.pathname + parent.location.search  + parent.location.hash
});
```